# MySQL use variable in WHILE loop

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I can't seem to find why this gives me an error. It can't use the variable 'art' in the loop.
But when I just do

```
 select art;
```

It gives me the correct number of items.

```
    drop procedure if exists bepaal_lijst_van_bij_te_bestellen_artikelen;

    delimiter //
    create procedure bepaal_lijst_van_bij_te_bestellen_artikelen()
    begin
        DECLARE art INT;
        DECLARE i INT;

        SELECT @art := COUNT(artikel_id) FROM artikelen;

        SET i = 1;
        WHILE i <= art DO

        END WHILE;
    end;
    //

    delimiter ;
```

Comment: it hurts the eyes to read this `bepaal_lijst_van_bij_te_bestellen_artikelen`! was there nothing simpler to choose?

Comment: yes there is. it hurts me too :)... but my university says I have to take this procedure name. I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly the while loop couldn't be empty and should contain something. fixed it by adding

```
SET i = 1 + i;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do

```
SET art := SELECT COUNT(artikel_id) FROM artikelen
```

Comment: This works now.

SELECT @art := COUNT(artikel_id) FROM artikelen;
SET doesn't work. However the while loop still doesn't want to fire up.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do (note: I know how the assignment goes)

```
SELECT count(*) from Items into art;
```